# Redefining sections, subsections, and subsubsections mess up \ref output

Tags: hyperref, labels, revtex, sections-paragraphs

I've redefined my sections as follows:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}
```

This looks great, until I want to reference a section in a different section.

Subsubsection reference (2 2.2 2.2.1, where it should just be 2.2.1):
[image: subsubsection reference]

Subsection reference (2 2.4, where it should just be 2.4):

[image: subsection reference]

My definition of labels and references is pretty straightforward i.e

```
\subsubsection{Dataset} \label{p:dataset}
```

and

```
For the training and evaluation of the CNNs we used the ADNI dataset described in \ref{p:dataset}
```

I would like to just keep the last part of the reference. For a section, this would just be N, for a subsection N.N and for a subsubsection N.N.N

Any suggestions?

Here's my preamble, and a quick reference section:

```
\documentclass[%
 superscriptaddress,
showpacs,preprintnumbers,
 amsmath,
 amssymb,
 aps,
 pra,
showkeys,
onecolumn,
notitlepage,
11pt,
tightenlines   % uncomment for double space
]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{hyperref}% add hypertext capabilities
\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewcommand*\footnoterule{}
\usepackage[
centering,
a4paper,
margin=2.0cm,
a4paper,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setsansfont[
BoldFont=ArialBold.ttf,
BoldItalicFont=ArialBoldItalic.ttf,
ItalicFont=ArialItalic.ttf
]{Arial.ttf}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\setmainfont{Arial}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% COLOR %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\definecolor{reddish}{HTML}{FBB4AE}
\definecolor{blueish}{HTML}{B3CDE3}
\definecolor{magentish}{HTML}{FF00AA}
\definecolor{greenish}{HTML}{a1d99b}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\red}[1]{{\sethlcolor{reddish}\hl{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\flow}[1]{\noindent{\sethlcolor{greenish}\hl{\textbf{FLOW} #1}}}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\blue}[1]{{\sethlcolor{blueish}\hl{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\magenta}[1]{{\sethlcolor{magentish}\hl{#1}}}

% \linespread{1.} 
% \linespread{1.6}
    
%%%% modifying APS template a bit:
% times 
% \usepackage{mathptmx}
% arabic number section
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}

% section left-side and title style
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\bfseries}
% FIG. -> Fig.
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
% spacing after and before section headers
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1ex plus 1ex minus .5ex}{0.5ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{1ex plus 1ex minus .5ex}{0.5ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1ex plus 1ex minus .5ex}{0.5ex}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{sort&compress, super}
\definecolor{blueish2}{HTML}{0830Bb}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true,
            linkcolor = blueish2,
            urlcolor = blueish2,
            citecolor = blueish2,
            anchorcolor = blueish2}
% section left-side and title style

\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section{References}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\fnum@figure}{{\normalfont\bfseries \figurename~\thefigure}}
\makeatother

\setlength{\bibsep}{2mm}
\setlength\bibhang{0.1in}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % Adjust the vertical padding here
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{caption} % add caption package
\usepackage{tabularx}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }


\begin{document}

\section{Intro}

my reference to the subsubsection \ref{p:dataset}

\section{Design}

\subsection{Datasets \& Preprocessing}

\subsubsection{Dataset} \label{p:dataset}

my text for this subsection

\end{document}
```

---

---

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}


\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}



\begin{document}

\section{Intro}

my reference to the subsubsection \ref{p:dataset}

\section{Design}

\subsection{Datasets \& Preprocessing}

\subsubsection{Dataset} \label{p:dataset}

my text for this subsection

\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on this site please provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. That makes it a lot easier to understand and test your setup and hopefully provide help.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes. References are accurate and link to the correct sections, however it's their display I don't like.

Comment: is that really the most minimal example that shows the problem? I can not run it as I don't have the fonts.

Comment: I added a more reasonable test document

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

revtex uses unprefixed subsection numbers in the heading, and adds prefixes to references. As you are prefixing the heading you need to not prefix references

[image]

```
\documentclass{revtex4-2}


\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}

\makeatletter
\let\p@section\@empty
\let\p@subsection\@empty
\let\p@subsubsection\@empty
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Intro}

my reference to the subsubsection \ref{p:dataset}

\section{Design}

\subsection{Datasets \& Preprocessing}

\subsubsection{Dataset} \label{p:dataset}

my text for this subsection

\end{document}
```

But do not do this for a journal submission. The whole point of revtex is that the publisher, not the author, chooses the house style.